# If I declare an instance variable as volatile, will the object of this class be volatile?

Tags: c++, volatile

Like:

```
class A
{
     volatile int i;
};


A a;
```

My question is that will the entire a become cv qualified? May be a naive question.

Comment: only what you declare `volatile` becomes one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, all of `a` will not be `volatile`.  Just as you can have fields of a class that are `const` without every instance of the class being `const`, you can have `volatile` fields that do not make the entire class instance `volatile`.